# How do I connect 2 classes with XIBs in my project?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a class for my iPhone app and I want to connect another class with .h .m .xib files to it for iPad. I know there are some ways to use only 1 class and 2 xib, but I want it another way. Also what do I need to write in app delegate so when loading my app it determines whether it is iPhone or iPad and choose the right class. I know there are many answers,but nothing works for me :/ Now I have app delegate.h app delegate.m  view controller.h view controller.m view controller.xib files. Thanks.

My appdelegate.h

```
@class SozdikViewController,iPadViewController;
@interface SozdikAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{

SozdikViewController *sozdikViewController;

iPadViewController *iPadViewController;

UIViewController *uiViewController;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property(strong,nonatomic) SozdikViewController *sozdikViewController;
@property (strong,nonatomic) iPadViewController *iPadViewController;

@end
```

appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
  if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
{
sozdikViewController=[[SozdikViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SozdikViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController=sozdikViewController;
 }
else if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
 sozdikViewController=[[SozdikViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SozdikViewController" bundle:nil];
         self.window.rootViewController=sozdikViewController;
}
}
else
{
 iPadViewController=[[[iPadViewController] alloc]initWithNibName:@"iPadViewController"bundle:nil];//this line doesn't work
self.window.rootViewController=iPadViewController//incompatible pointer types assigning  to 'UIViewController*'from'iPadViewController*' message appears;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Place the code of your appdelegate.m under your question..What you have tried..!

Comment: Check whether you imported SozdikViewController,iPadViewController in AppDelegate.h or not....like #import "SozdikViewController.h" #import "iPadViewController.h"

Comment: ok I imported them just right now, but still doesn't work.Any more ideas?

Comment: Import them at AppDelegate.m also and check..

Comment: Already done.Still AppDelegate.m for some reasons does not see iPadViewController class.

Comment: Make sure you synthesized the declared view controller references and also import them at start of AppDelegate.m

Comment: synthesized too)) but still not working)

Comment: when i start to type "s", Xcode automatically gives options to create sozdikViewController variable and class. but when i type "i" Xcode allows only to create iPadViewController variable.

Comment: Remove and Create iPadViewController again with different name..If possible.It may fix the issue..!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
   //do all your initialisation for the iPad
}
else{
   //do all your initialisation for the iPhone
}
```

You have to put this snippet of code in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method, in your appDelegate.m. Make sure you include both classes (iPad and iPhone) in your appDelegate, and you create objects of both classes in the AppDelegate.h file.

Answer (score 0):

```
UINib *nib;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"viewController_iphone" bundle:nil];
else
    nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"viewController_ipad" bundle:nil];
```

But another option is you can give it name like if iphone xib then you can name as `viewController.xib` and for iPad `viewController~ipad.xib`. so you don't need to write condition. you just have to write `UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:nil];`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write below code in AppDelegate to load Initial screen. Same can be used in your view controller to push to another screens..In this case I want to load LoginViewController after application launches...Modify as per you need.

AppDelegate.h declare

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController * navigationcontroller;
@property (strong, nonatomic) LoginViewController *loginViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {


            if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
            {
                loginViewController=[[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iphone4s" bundle:nil];
            }
           else if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
            {
                 loginViewController=[[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iphone5" bundle:nil];

            }


         }

    else
    {
         loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];

    }

    navigationcontroller=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationcontroller;
    [ navigationcontroller setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Hope it Helps you...!

Comment: Thanks. But don't you know why my app delegate doesn't see the second's class I've created. Look I've declared 2 classes in .h file. 
@property (strong,nonatomic) iPadViewController *iPadViewController and the same for SozdikVieController; 1st is: "sozdikViewController" and the second is "iPadViewController". In the .m file when I write self.window.rootViewController=sozdikViewController it works fine. But when i write self.window.rootViewController=iPadViewController. "Incompatible pointer types assigning  yo 'UIViewController*' from 'iPadViewController*'" message appears.

Comment: You need to create iPadViewController as subclass of UIViewController. Place you app delegate code in your question..

Comment: Problem lies with iPadViewController..Remove it and create again with same or different name. Remember it should be subclass to UIViewController..!